# Error of popup box: unable to locate element, using

Tags: cucumber, watir-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote this code in console: `@b.text_field(:name => 'popupbox[title]').set 'Title'`

There was no error, all works.

I wrote this code in step definition: `@b.text_field(:name => 'popupbox[title]').set 'Title'`

An error occured: unable to locate element, using...

I use Chrome. In Firefox everything works, but nothing works in Chrome...

Where is a problem?

**Gemfile:**

```
group :test do      
  gem 'watir-webdriver'  
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'    
  gem 'cucumber'    
  gem 'cucumber-rails'    
  gem 'database_cleaner'    
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'    
  gem 'rspec-rails'    
  gem 'spork'    
  gem 'watchr'    
  gem 'capybara'    
  gem 'email_spec'    
  gem 'watir-page-helper'      
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's working in IRB and not in the browser, it could be a timing issue.  If you're using watir-webdriver you could try using:

```
@b.text_field(:name => "popupbox[title]").when_present.set("Title")
```

If this does not help, is the text field displayed on the page when the error occurs?  If not, you may have forgotten a step that you need to take on the webpage before the text field occurs.

I'm assuming this text field appears after an action, due to the "popupbox" name on it.